# How to concat the list of sequential strings including partially same string

Tags: python-2.7

For example, this is the list of strings.

```
a = 'abcdefg'
b = 'efghij'
c = 'ij234235'
d = 'def'
e = 'efg'
f = 'fg'

str_list = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

I expect that the result would be `['abcdefghij234235', 'defg']`

The concatenation should be executed sequentially and the common strings are not fixed

How can I get the result?

Comment: why it should end up with 2 items? Why not `'abcdefghij234235defg'` ?

Comment: You should start by thinking about a solution and trying to implement it. In Stackoverflow we expect the users to try to solve their own problem first before they post it here, and then show us what they tried and how it failed.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Because the variables have the common strings between end-of-string and start-of-string. For instance, the variable `a` ends with `efg` and the variable `b` starts with `efg`.

Comment: @alfasin I tried using the function of `longest common subsequence` algorithm. And I put the LCS function into a recursive function to repeat concatenation in the list.

Comment: @ChangminChoi it's actually even simpler than that because what you're looking is only longest-common-**substring** that start at the end of one string and at the beginning of the other. This restriction makes it much easier to find. Pay attention that you're looking for a common substring - not subsequence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th solution using [**`numpy.intersect1d`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) and `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` functions:

```
import numpy as np, itertools

str_list = [list(a), list(b), list(c), list(d), list(e), list(f)]
result = []

for k,a in enumerate(str_list):
    if len(result) == 0:
        result.append((str_list[k],))

    if k+1 == len(str_list): break

    common = ''.join(np.intersect1d(str_list[k],str_list[k+1]))
    if common and common[-1] == ''.join(str_list[k])[-1] and common[0] in ''.join(str_list[k+1])[0]:
        result[-1] += (str_list[k+1][len(common):],)
    else:
        result.append((str_list[k+1],))

result = [''.join(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(t))) for t in result]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['abcdefghij234235', 'defg']
```